# Calling function within function, when self is not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia

I have two functions, `handleTouch`, and `handleDoubleTap`.-

```
%hook MKMapGestureController

-(void)handleTouch:(id)arg1{
    %orig;
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(id)arg1{
    %orig;
}

%end
```

Now what I would like to do, is swap handleTouch and handleDoubleTap around. So that when either one is called, technically the other one is called.

I tried `[self handleTouch];`, to which I got two errors

`error: receiver type 'MKMapGestureController' for instance message is a forward declaration`

`note: forward declaration of class here`

I've tried that, along with replacing `self` with `MKMapGestureController`, and a few other things all of which failed.

Comment: import mapkit.h in your class.

Comment: Hi, logged into other account, I don't have a mapkit.h, only a MapKit.framework, and I cannot include/import that